# Unable to open PDF file using java command line

Tags: java, pdf, command-line, itext

I am trying to open a PDF file from java using the command line argument as

```
String command = "cmd /c start AcroRd32.exe \"" + dir + "\"";
```

But i am getting an error when the file will be automatically opened as

```
"Windows cannot find 'acroRd32.exe'. Please make sure you typed the correct name."
```

However i am able to open it manually without using the command line/java.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you do it [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) way instead.

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("c:/some/file.pdf");
java.awt.Desktop.open(file);
```

If you still want to run "AcroRd32.exe" (or some other "command") use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), with something like this -

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("AcroRd32.exe", dir);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thats definitely the better way to do that, since it opens the default application for PDF that the user has installed, eg. FoxIt reader.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this is really useful but it works to open pdf file.

```
String FileName="C:/name.pdf";//Write your complete path here
try {
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + FileName);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: If this is not useful then plz provide comment that why it is not useful. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
String cmds[] = new String[] {"cmd", "/c",  "C:\\test.pdf"};  
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
START C:\temp\My_PDF_File.pdf use this command for opening from command line
```

other wise use class [desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)