# Open pdf file with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, itext

Can i open a PDF file created with iText simply running the class in Eclipse environment?This is the main code that creates the PDF file and stores it in a default folder

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
       Document document = new Document();
       PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
       document.open();
       aggiungiMetaDati(document);
       //aggiungiPrefazione(document);
       aggiungiContenuto(document);
       document.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "open the PDF file"? iText isn't a PDF viewer, nor is Eclipse, so you'll need an external viewer. See [Unable to open PDF file using java command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301190/unable-to-open-pdf-file-using-java-command-line) to get some ideas on how to call such a viewer from code.

Comment: thank you very much I followed the guide you suggested and now opens the file with the default viewer

Comment: OK, glad my answer helped you. I closed the question to prevent link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [Desktop.open()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-)?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10389296)

Comment: @YoungHobbit Considering that the link works all the way back to `5.0` (and older ones can be downloaded from the archive), I'd say Oracle's javadoc links are pretty safe.